# Connecting to GitLab repositories on Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitlab, googleio

I'm trying to connect to a GitLab repository using the I/O preview of Android Studio. Does anyone know how to do this/if it is possible yet?

Comment: it's a pity Android Studio doesn't have a "GitLab" entry for File -> Settings -> Version Control. There's only a "GitHub" option and it's not compatible with GitLab. It seems to me, that GitHub is promoted over GitLab

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### To clone a repo

Open a new project in Android Studio.

Click `VCS -> Checkout from version control -> Git`

then enter the URL of the repo and your local direcory

### To commit

Open the project you want to push in Android Studio.

Click `VCS -> Enable version Control -> Git`

There does't seem to be a way to add a remote through the GUI. So open Git Bash in the root of the project add do `git remote add <remote_name> <remote_url>`.

Now when you do `VCS -> Commit changes -> Commit & Push` you should see your remote and everything should work through the GUI.

---

See these pages for details:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-git-integration.html

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87099

Comment: Worked for me "preconfiguring" the folder with the mac console (terminal)

Comment: Now you can add remote using GUI by clicking on GIT -> Manage Remotes

Answer (score 112):

## How to add an Android Studio project to GitLab

This answer shows how to do it using the Android Studio GUI.

### 1. Create a new project on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com)

Chose the `+` button on the menu bar. Add a project name and then click "Create project".

[image]

This will give you a new project address. Choose the https version.

[image]

It will look something like this:

```
https://gitlab.com/MyUserName/my-project.git
```

#### 2. Create a Git repository in Android Studio

In the Android Studio menu go to **VCS > Import into Version Control > Create Git Repository...**

[image]

Select the root directory of your project. (It will be automatically selected if you already have it highlighted in the Project view. Otherwise you will have to browse up to find it.)

#### 3. Add remote

Go to **VCS > Git > Remotes...**. Then paste in the https address you got from GitLab in step one.

[image]

You may need to log in with your GitLab username and password.

#### 4. Add, commit, and push your files

Make sure you have the top level of the project selected. If you are in the Android view you can switch it to the Project view.

[image]

- *Add:* Go to **VCS > Git > Add**.
- *Commit:* After adding, do **VCS > Git > Commit Directory**. (You will need to write a commit message, something like `initial commit`.)
- *Push:* Finally, go to  **VCS > Git > Push**.

#### Finished!

You should be able to view your files in GitLab now.

## See also

There is a plugin that would probably streamline the process. Check it out [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7975-gitlab-projects).

Comment: i got this error Remote URL test failed: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/codenex/shopping.git/

Comment: @Suragch Sir I am getting url like this http://192.168.0.52/pvijayalakshmi/eEmployee.git from step 1: But When I enter this url in android studio, It is giving me this Error:Remote URL test failed: Unable to find remote helper for 'http'

Comment: it slightly changed since 2017 now its VCS > Get from Version Control,  then select Git, give the url and the local directory of the gitlab project. It will do the steps 2 and 3 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CodeStream](https://www.codestream.com/) plugin, easy configuration

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30835510)