# Connect my project to gitlab with android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitlab

my friend have create a project on gitlab, when i signin gitlab i view project xxxxx/project if i click on it, i enter in project and i can select link ssh or httsp.
For example link https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/myproject.git
If i click link repository: https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/myproject/tree/master there are three directory:
client/myprojecty, 
 server/myserverproject,
 sketch/mysketchserver

Project android is in client/myprojecty, now i want connect my local project that is located into C://User/AndroiStudioProject/myproject with client/project and i want use android studio.

I don't want that client/myproject overwrite my local project C://User/AndroidStudio/myproject

How do i with android studio?

I have try when starup android studio:
Check out project from Version Control
then i click git
Then open dialg Clone  Repository where there is text field to fill:

Git Reposiroy Url: https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/myproject.git
Parent Directory: C://User/AndroiStudioProject/myproject
Directory Name: myproject

I have not clicked clone because i'm scared that this command overwrite my local project and delete all progress in my local project.

How i do only connect my local project with project on gitlab?
Then how i update my progress?

Comment: Is the remote project the same as your project ? You want remote be updated with you or reverse ?

Comment: I want updated project on gitlab with my local project, my lates version is on my pc the old version is on gitlab

Comment: So there are changes in your local project that you want to overwrite to serverside ?

Comment: I want to make sure everything will be ok. No new changes on the remote side to be copied to local version ?

Comment: Yes i want overwrite on serverside

Comment: One another question have your local project ever been controlled by git ?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677931/connecting-to-gitlab-repositories-on-android-studio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all make a copy of your project folder (do it always when doing these kind of things just in case)

Then open your project and go terminal tab in android studio and type

```
   git init
```

Now your local project is controlled by git. But how to connect it to your remote project is like below:

```
git remote add origin [the address of your remote repo]
```

Then just type:

```
git add .
```

And commit your changes like below:

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Then type this to push on server:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: why i can't copy and past in to terminal?

Comment: You dont need to copy from terminal. Find the project file and just copy it and paste it in sone other path.

Comment: @Fra87 there is a tick icon under the votes count in my answer. click on that.

Comment: Hey, I got this error after followed the above steps. Please help me solve this. 

remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
fatal: unable to access 'GIT URL': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Do I have to add any permissions to revoke this?

Comment: @ParthBhayani this means you do not have push access to that repo. go to your git panel and add push permission to your account.