# How to add an Android Studio project to GitLab

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitlab

I referred this link: 
[Connecting to GitLab repositories on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677931/connecting-to-gitlab-repositories-on-android-studio)

In step 1, I am getting this

> https://gitlab.com/pvijayalakshmi/eemployee.git

[image: URL starts with http]

In step3, I am getting this error:

> Remote URL test failed: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

[image]

[image]
Why I am getting this error?

Please help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow a tutorial from Github, the principle is the same: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/
Basically, you need to add `git` to your local project, commit all the changes and set up remote repository URL:

```
git remote add origin remote repository URL
```

Then you push your code to the remote repository.

Comment: I dont want to integrate with GITHUB. I want to integrate with GITLAB@Angelina

Comment: @vishnu the command line commands are exactly the same. just use your gitlab url in setting remote url. see here: https://usersnap.com/blog/gitlab-github/ they both use a program called `git`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a project to Gitlab manually,  Get project repo URL &
   Clone the project locally by using the terminal. One last step Now add your files in the local folder.

Comment: I don't understand this URL:http://192.168.0.52/pvijayalakshmi/eEmployee.git,
The host looks invalid "192.168.0.52"
Your project URL should be something: https://gitlab.com/yourUsername/projectname.git

Comment: ok. I have created account and paste the url now:https://gitlab.com/pvijayalakshmi/eemployee.git. Now also getting the error