# How to import Gitlab project into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gitlab, android-studio-3.0

In my company we have one android project into [gitlab.com](http://gitlab.com) and into this project we **pushed** a lot of **commits**.
Now i want add this project into my personal system and when use **Check out project from version control** button show me one window and i paste my project link from **Giltab** but when click on **Text** button show me error messages and not add project into my personal system!

When go to **Gitlab** for see project should use **username** and **password**.

My android studio version is 3.3.1

**My error image :** 
[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: Try to login github first and rename the directory path. You tried to get a project that already in this directory.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed, why login to Github ? my project has into Giltab !

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677931/connecting-to-gitlab-repositories-on-android-studio

Comment: @FaysalAhmed, i used this way but again show me error!